# sql, php, html table question

Tags: php, sql

I want to grab data from a mysql database by using php. The data looks something like this:

```
apple 3
orange 2
banana 4
```

I want to take the data and put it in a html table and use css to make it look pretty, but I dont want to deal with it inside `<?php ?>`

After I grab the

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table");`

can I reference the result variable outside the `<? php ?>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. PHP can only be done in `<?php ... ?>` or `<?= ... ?>`. Use a template engine such as Smarty if you want substitution in this manner.

Comment: so how would u put the data in a html table?

Comment: @SuperString: Easiest way would be to assign all the results to an array or object and loop through it in your view. After all, PHP in itself is a templating language :)

Comment: or use AJAX and `json_encode` the data on the php side.  i would try to avoid smarty

Answer (score 1):

in short, no you cant, it is a php variable (technically a resource in this case) so you have to parse it through the php engine, which requires the php tags

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['fruit'].'</td><td>'.$row['id'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. HTML cannot deal with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut down the amount of echo statements within your code you can store the html within a given variable and then make reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I find it better to do the following:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($result as $row): ?>

   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['fruit']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
   </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

This provides clarity and minimizes concatenation.